# restore from s3 bucket to sql server getting error Database backup/restore option is not enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services

I got this kind of error when I tried to restore from s3 bucket

--error message

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Procedure msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database,
> Line 49 [Batch Start Line 0]
>
> Database backup/restore option is not
> enabled yet or is in the process of being enabled. Please try again
> later. USAGE: EXECUTE msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name,
> @S3_arn_to_restore_from, [@KMS_master_key_arn] @restore_db_name : Name
> of the database being restored. @S3_arn_to_restore_from : S3 ARN of
> the backup file used to restore database from. @KMS_master_key_arn :
> KMS customer master key ARN to decrypt the backup file with.

--executed code

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
@restore_db_name='C2', 
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::slkk/31_May_2019_C2.bak';
```

I am using aws free account. How do I enable backup restore?

Answer (score 48):

Go to IAM and create new Role with Permissions as follow:

- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForRestores
- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup

[image]

Go to RDS > Option groups

- Create group (Name: SqlServerBackupRestore, Description: xxx, Engine: Select your DB engine, Major Engine Version: Select version of your DB instance.
- Click Create

[image]

Once group is created, click the name of created group to Edit.

- Click Add option
- Select option: SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE
- Select IAM role you created in previous steps
- Select Immediately to schedule instant change

[image]

Back to RDS > Databases and select your instance

- Click Modify
- Select Option group you created in previous step

[image]

- Click Next
- Select Apply immediately (it should not cause service downtime)

[image]

- Apply changes by clicking Modify DB instance
- If you have connection to DB from SQL Management Studio please close and connect again.

Comment: So many details. It wasn't until I noticed the final "...please close and connect again" instruction that I finally got this working, and I had been through the process once before for a server in a different VPC. Thanks @Dariusz!

Comment: I will add that someone else had SSMS open with a connection to the DB in concern and they also had to close their connection.

Comment: This helped us get past this error, and it said that the restore was created, but the database doesn't pop up right away, and I can't figure out a way to tell if it's doing anything... Any way to monitor the progress, or tell if anything is happening at all?

Comment: The role to be created is for trust entity "RDS - Add Role to Database" and I had to also add a policy for S3 access to the bucket my backup file is in.

Comment: In addition to the two Permissions mentioned at the beginning, I had to add AmazonS3FullAccess. Before I did that, I kept getting an Access Denied error when running `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database`

Comment: @AndyD273 Yes. To monitor progress: `exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;`

Comment: use "EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;" to check the status of the restore operation

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. However, I need to add         "Principal": {"Service":  "rds.amazonaws.com"}, in the trust relationship of the role.  https://serverfault.com/questions/798380/aws-add-option-group; and change the policy like : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Enabling.IAM

Comment: A little out of date, and also needed to add AmazonS3FullAccess permission to the role, but this helped.

Comment: Just for complement the official guide for backup and restore from Microsoft SQL Server is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I ran into the same error and was able to resolve it so I thought I'd share since this was unanswered.

First, this article details what you need, so make sure you follow these steps:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/

I had setup the Options Group and everything initially.  The steps I missed were these two:

> 3. Associate the option group with the DB instance by choosing Databases in the navigation pane, and then choose the instance to back up. Choose Actions, and then choose Modify.
> 4. Under Database Options, choose the option group that you created, and then choose Apply Immediately and Continue. Review the information, and then choose Modify DB Instance. This option group modification has no downtime because instance reboot is not required.

In other words, you have to modify the actual database instance with the new `Option Group` that was setup in those steps.  Then once you login to your instance via SSMS, you can execute the restore by executing (taken from the article):

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
    @restore_db_name='database_name', 
    @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension';
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating the IAM role first and then adding that to options not working for some reason, I tried with admin policy in that role also doesn't work for me.

rather than creating the IAM role ourselves first, In the RDS **Add Option** for choosing the role, there is an option to **creating a new role** use this option and select the s3 bucket name this will create the correct policy and IAM role for us, It works perfectly also helped this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbJvyQEjZ8k.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For some reason choosing 'SQLSERVER_AUDIT' in the option group solved it for me, as opposed to the seemingly logical 'SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE'

Answer (score 0):

Folowed few tutorials:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/

**Here is what solved my case:**

I added below to my IAM role created while instance was built:

[image]

Also [setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.ResetPassword.html) new password for `Master username` seems to have did the trick as after that `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database` started to work.