# Stored procedure error in AWS RDS: S3_INTEGRATION Feature is not enabled or is in the process of being enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I got this kind of error when I tried to load data into RDS from S3

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Procedure dbo.rds_download_from_s3, Line 114 [Batch Start Line 2]
S3_INTEGRATION Feature is not enabled or is in the process of being enabled. Please try again later
```

I am using custom stored procedures provided by AWS RDS. These are located in the msdb database. The stored procedure to download files from S3 is "rds_download_from_s3".

--executed code

```
    @return_value = [dbo].[rds_download_from_s3]
    @s3_arn_of_file= N'arn:aws:s3:::dev-curated/ops/output.csv',
    @rds_file_path = N'D:\S3\dev-curated\ops\output.csv',
    @overwrite_file = 1
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you gone through this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html

Comment: @riz Yes, I have gone through this and provided necessary permissions to my s3

Comment: Hi @adey27, I don't know how how you set you your db, what procedure have you followed but I can provide you with another link which seems to be a similar issue. Mayeb you have gone through it as well..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005157/restore-from-s3-bucket-to-sql-server-getting-error-database-backup-restore-optio